# function add new input

Tags: php, function, cakephp

I have add_person.ctp file, and there I have Inputs and function, but this function is not working, My question is why its not working, I dont see any mistake in this code. If I click button, then this doing nothing.

Here is my code

```
<h2>People</h2>
    <table id="mytable">
    <tr><th></th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Gender</th></tr>
    <tr id="person0" style="display:none;">
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this person')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.lastName',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.firstName',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.email',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.gender',array('label'=>'','type'=>'select','options'=>array('M'=>'M','F'=>'F','T'=>'T'))); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another person','onclick'=>'addPerson()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>

    <?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-2.1.1.min.js'));?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var lastRow=0;

    function addPerson() {
        lastRow++;
        $("#mytable tbody>tr:#person0").clone(true).attr('id','person'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
        $("#person"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removePerson('+lastRow+')');
        $("#person"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('name','data[Person]['+lastRow+'][lastName]').attr('id','personLastName'+lastRow);
        $("#person"+lastRow+" input:eq(1)").attr('name','data[Person]['+lastRow+'][firstName]').attr('id','personFirstName'+lastRow);
        $("#person"+lastRow+" input:eq(2)").attr('name','data[Person]['+lastRow+'][email]').attr('id','personEmail'+lastRow);
        $("#person"+lastRow+" select").attr('name','data[Person]['+lastRow+'][gender]').attr('id','personGender'+lastRow);
    }

    function removePerson(x) {
        $("#person"+x).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong selector here `#mytable tbody>tr:#person0` and here `#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd`. Replace with `#mytable tbody>tr#person0` and `#mytable tbody>tr#trAdd` respectively. Keep in mind there is no need to use colon symbol in selectors.